# How can I reliably check for Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-analytics

It used to be so simple - this was all that was needed to ensure you could go ahead and track a user's click or whatever:

```
if ('ga' in window && window.ga !== undefined && typeof window.ga === 'function') {
...
```

Now, Firefox's 'tracking protection' is here, and that doesn't work. Why? Well, even though the Firefox JS console claims

> The resource at "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled.

The 'if' test above still returns true. So, I ask you, how can I reliably check if Google Analytics is available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to check that the GA tracker has been created:

```
ga(function() {
  // Logs an array of all tracker objects.
  console.log(ga.getAll());
});
```

(cf. [getAll() method](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/accessing-trackers#getall))

Comment: Perfect! I'm using (window.ga.getAll !== undefined && typeof window.ga.getAll === 'function') as a test and that works great. Many thanks.